# Interfacing mems digital microphone with ESP32

Tags: esp32, microphone, mems-microphone

The datasheet of the microphone mentions:

> **Source termination resistors are used to match the impedance of the source and the trace.**
> **The component values of the termination resistors depend on the properties of the trace they are on; typical values range from 50 to 100 Ohms.**

I am new to electronic design could not understand this, as I haven't calculated trace impedance before.

What does *"the impedance of the source"* mean? Do I have to match the pin impedance of the ESP32 for clock and data pins to the trace of clock pin and data pin on the microphone?

Also, I am planning to attach this PCB at 6-inch distance from the PCB where the ESP32 is attached. I was planning to attach together both PCBs with wire solder on pads. Now do I also need to calculate the impedance of these wires?

Comment: it helped a lot thank you. my confusion is that esp32 pins has their own impedance which are very high could not find their exact value do i need to consider that also?

Comment: If this were a very long cable you should look up the pin's source impedance and choose a resistor that sums with it to match the trace impedance. However for a few inches and an audio clock signal your probably don't need to do this and instead could put a somewhat higher resistor (~100 ohms) to limit the rise time rather than match the impedance. This will stretch out your rising edges but your clock is so low that won't be a problem.